# Form with Post Method and enctype Multipart/form-data is not being submitted on Nodejs Express multer module

Tags: node.js, forms, express, ejs, multer

I am using :

```
"ejs": "^2.5.6",
"express": "^4.14.0",
"express-validator": "^3.2.0",
"multer": "^1.3.0",
```

My form is :

```
     <form id="offer-form" role="form" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/subfolder/86" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="name"/>
    <input type="file" name="images"/>
<input type="file" name="images"/>
    <button type="submit">Submit</submit>
    </form>
```

My server route:

```
var path = require('path');
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var expressValidator = require('express-validator');
var osmodule = require('../../osmodule');
var Multer = require('multer');
var request = require('request');
const multer = Multer({
    storage: Multer.memoryStorage(),
    limits: {
        fileSize: 5 * 1024 * 1024 // no larger than 5mb, you can change as needed.
    }
});


  //Adding a new subfolder
        app.post('/subfolder/:id', multer.array({ name: 'images', maxCount: 6 }), expressValidator, function (req, res, next) {
console.log("Form Submitted");
       }).use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
    res.status(404).send('Not Found ! ');
    });
```

Normally this code should print on the console the message

> Form submitted
>   but the server is receiving nothing not even 
>   Not Found

I have just noticed the problem is with using multer and expressValidator. If I remove expressValidator, it is working but if I add it, it is not working. I need expressValidator to validate user data. Is there any other validator which will accept to be used with multer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution of using both of these middlewares, I just called the before the action and called the express-validator after calling multer:

```
var path = require('path');
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var expressValidator = require('express-validator');
var osmodule = require('../../osmodule');
var Multer = require('multer');
var request = require('request');
const multer = Multer({
    storage: Multer.memoryStorage(),
    limits: {
        fileSize: 5 * 1024 * 1024 // no larger than 5mb, you can change as needed.
    }
});

app.get('/home',function(req,res){
console.log("Welcome Brother");
})
.use(multer.array({ name: 'images', maxCount: 6 });
.use(expressValidator);
.post('/subfolder/:id', function (req, res, next) {
console.log("Form Submitted");
       }).use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
    res.status(404).send('Not Found ! ');
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this might be due to the validator not being initialize properly.
Try the following by adding the following two lines  before the `app.post`.

**INIT**

```
app.use(bodyParser.json()); //To enable post request over node api.
app.use(expressValidator([options])); // this line must be immediately after any of the bodyParser middlewares!
```

Then you configure your validation **inside** the `app.post`

```
req.checkBody('postparam', 'Invalid postparam').notEmpty().isInt();
```

See all the available [**options**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-validator#usage)

Remember to remove **expressValidator** from the current app.post method above

Comment: I am putting it on post because I want it to be used only on that route not on the app in general. If I put it the way you are asking me to do it will be used by the app in general @conrad Lotz